# Crear batch para recorrer carpetas dinamicamente

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo un problema extraño con un archivo BAT en **Windows** y no se muy bien que esta pasando.

He creado un archivo bat para recorrer las carpetas que le indico por parametros. En la carpeta del bat, tengo una carpeta app y quiero obtener todos los archivos que hay dentro de esta, en las carpetas que indique.

La llamada seria algo como

```
mibat.bat folder1 folder2 folder3.
```

En el archivo bat tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (

    echo Recorriendo la carpeta %%a
    set parameterFolder = %%a
    set parameterPath = app\%parameterFolder%

    for /R %parameterPath% %%v in (*.js) do (
        echo %%v
    )

)
```

El problema es que la ruta del for no la esta cogiendo correctamente y me saca todos los arvhivos js que hay dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra el bat, y no dentro de `app\folder1`, `app\folder2` o `app\folder3...`

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto ???

Comment: por si sirve, mi idea es unificar todos los archivos js de una web, de carpetas especificas... este archivo lo asociare en VS para que lo ejecute antes de compilar y así automatizar esa unificación de archivos... ya que mi aplicacion esta hecha en angularjs... y de esta forma solo tendre un archivo con todos los controladores...

Comment: es logico , debes colocar la ruta absoluta o colocar el bat en la raiz

Comment: el bat si que me lo localiza y me lo ejecuta correctamente, si en el `for pongo directamente for /R app\folder1 %%v in (*.js) do (echo %%v)` tambien funciona correctamente... el problema esta cuando lo hago dinamico para que monte los path con los parametros de entrada... que el for toma como raiz la carpeta del BAT y no las que indico...

Comment: hay alguna forma de compartiros un paquete para que veais el resultado ???

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en un fichero bat, las variables no se actualizan dentro de un FOR o un IF:

Es decir, este código:

```
set FOO=BAR
if 1==1 (
  set FOO=CAMBIADO
  echo %FOO%
)
```

Imprime `BAR`

Para solucionarlo, tienes que utilizar la directia `setlocal enabledelayeedexpansion` y referenciar a las variables entre signos de exclamación (en lugar de porcentajes)

El código de antes quedaría así:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOO=BAR
if 1==1 (
  set FOO=CAMBIADO
  echo !FOO!
)
```

Imprime `CAMBIADO`

Así pues, tu código debería arreglarse cambiado lo siguiente:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%*) do (

    echo Recorriendo la carpeta %%a
    set parameterFolder = %%a
    set parameterPath = app\!parameterFolder!

    for /R !parameterPath! %%v in (*.js) do (
        echo %%v
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenos dias necesito recorrer un fichero para leer valores de un archivo de configuración, cuando tengo un valor, recogo la dirección del servidor, el nombre de usuario y el password

```
configuracion.txt
    open 10.0.0.4
    administrador
    abcd1234

set fichConexion=conexion.txt

@echo on
for /F %%A IN (Q:\PROYECTOS\ftp 10.0.0.4 practicasadmi2\ftp_conf_func_log_mail\ultima_version\conexion.txt) DO @ECHO %%A
for /F %%A IN (%fichConexion%) DO @ECHO %%A
pause>nul
```

Mi problema es cuando tengo varios usuarios en el archivo de configuración.

```
configuracion.txt
    open 10.0.0.4
    administrador
    pepito1234
    open 10.0.0.5
    administrador
    grillo1234
```

Una vez que coge los datos de usuario el segundo paso es ejecutar un bat que recogiengo esos datos se conecta a servidor via ftp y descarga unos ficheros..
¿Alguien podria ayudarme?
habia pensado hacer un for dentro de otro for